# Mysql selecting (n) rows of each occurrance

Tags: mysql, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [mysql: Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

I need to perform a select that will return (n) number of records per unique us_state.

Basically, I would like to find an equivalent to TOP(n), but since MySQL doesn't support that, is there a similar command or method I can use to shortcut having to right specialized code to perform the same operation?

Thanks.

Comment: `Top n` does not return the top per state.  Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: Basically, I want a sample of, say 5, records for each occurrance of a state in the us_states column. I have someone that wants samples from each and would prefer to not have to write code to do that.

Comment: @bluefeet - Write your comment up as an answer. I'll just accept yours as it's likely going to get me much closer to a solution using the self-join method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is select a number of records per group. This can be done by using variables in your query similar to this:

```
select *
from
(
    SELECT sid, 
        state, 
        votes,
        @prev := @curr,
        @curr := state,
        @rank := IF(@prev = @curr, @rank+1, 1) AS rank
    FROM
    (
      select t1.sid, state, votes
      FROM table1 t1
      INNER JOIN table2 t2
          ON t1.sid=t2.sid
    ) src, (SELECT @curr := null, @prev := null, @rank := 1) r
    ORDER BY state, votes desc
) src
where rank <= 2
order by state, votes;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c86c1/1)

There are other ways to do this which are outlined here:

[Using LIMIT within GROUP BY to get N results per group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/mysql-using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group)

Answer (score 0):

[Limit optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/limit-optimization.html) in MySQL does just that.

---

## Edit

Since you want them order by some type of column or something, you also need [ORDER BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) clause.

Comment: They don't necessarily have to be ordered. Just need a sampling of n number of records for each distinct occurrence of a us state in my states column.