# bottom N from multiple possible groups

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the bottom N values from a table taking into account that multiple categories or types are inserted.

**my table:**

```
CREATE TABLE `Table1` (
    `name` VARCHAR(250) NOT NULL,
    `total` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `type` INT(11) NOT NULL
)
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**Some values:**

```
|| *name*       || *total*  || *type*   ||

|| Clock        || 12       || 103      ||

|| Brief Case   || 21       || 103      ||

|| Pencil       || 34       || 103      ||

|| Lollypop     || 45       || 103      ||

|| Notebook     || 67       || 142      ||

|| Rubber Band  || 3        || 143      ||

|| Smartphone   || 1        || 143      ||
```

**What I got so far:**

```
SELECT name,total from Table1 ORDER BY TOTAL ASC LIMIT 3 where type=143;
```

but I need the same result for every category with one query.

**Tried this:**

```
SELECT name,total from Table1 ORDER BY TOTAL ASC LIMIT 3 GROUP BY type;
```

but this is wrong. As expected, I retrieve just 3 records from all records instead 3 from every category.

[possible duplicate]
[Mysql selecting (n) rows of each occurrance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14326949/mysql-selecting-n-rows-of-each-occurrance)

Comment: I don't think it's possible to do so with one mysql query, except if you know all types in advance (then you can make long and ugly UNION of all of them)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT name,total from Table1 as t1
WHERE t1.name in (SELECT t2.name FROM Table1 as t2 WHERE t1.type = t2.type ORDER BY t2.TOTAL ASC LIMIT 3)
```